# помогите инициализировать двухмерный массив

Tags: c++, массивы, инициализация

Делаю вот так :

```
constexpr int A = 2; 
constexpr int B = 5;

struct prasetoReplace {
  std::wstring find;
  std::wstring replace;
};
extern const std::array <std::array<prasetoReplace, A>,B> aaa;
```

хочу aaa проинициализировать в другом файле. поэтому пытаюсь так :

```
const std::array <std::array<prasetoReplace, A>, B> aaa =
{
    {{L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"},{L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"},{L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"},{L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"},{L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"}},
    { {L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"},{L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"},{L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"},{L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"},{L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"}},
    { {L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"},{L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"},{L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"},{L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"},{L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"}},
    { {L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"},{L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"},{L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"},{L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"},{L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"}}
    { {L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"},{L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"},{L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"},{L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"},{L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"}}



};
```

но не выходит )) что я делаю не так ?

Comment: `X` и `Y` - не вижу определений. Они должны быть константами. И такими-же как `A` и `B`.

Comment: *"не выходит"* не является описанием проблемы.

Comment: @AlexGlebe. извините, писал второпях. вопрос подправил.

Comment: Количество задаёте пять пар, а  внутренний массив определён с размером 2.

Comment: @AlexGlebe https://www.online-cpp.com/osNZnQ0mra

Comment: `X` - это внутренний размер. количество столбцов , а не строк.

Comment: @AlexGlebe   тогда почему инициализация интового массива с такими же размерами работает ???online-cpp.com/osNZnQ0mra

Comment: потому,что без фигурных скобок, ограничивающих строки инициализация идёт для всех подряд элементов. *(**не** так как вы написали)*

Answer (score 1):

Фигурный скобки при иницализации переменной основываются на его типе. А если приведены очень много вложенных друг в друга скобок, то автоматическое определение типов не работает. Нужно указывать компилятору какой именно тип вы имеете в виду.

```
# include <string>
# include <array>

constexpr int A = 2; 
constexpr int B = 5;

struct prasetoReplace {
  std::wstring find;
  std::wstring replace;
};

extern const std::array <std::array<prasetoReplace, A>,B> aaa;

const std::array <std::array<prasetoReplace, A>, B> aaa = {
    std::array<prasetoReplace, A> {
      prasetoReplace {L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"},{L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"}},
    { prasetoReplace {L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"},{L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"}},
    { prasetoReplace {L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"},{L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"}},
    { prasetoReplace {L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"},{L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"}},
    { prasetoReplace {L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"},{L"1 ракушек", L"1 ракушку"}}};
```

---

Чтобы понять проблему : вот минимальный пример неоднозначности выполнения конструктора.

```
class A{
public:
  A(int x):i{x}{}
  int i;
};

class B{
public:
  B(int x):i{x}{}
  int i;
};

class C{
public:
  C(A a):i{a.i}{}
  C(B b):i{b.i}{}
  int i;
};

// error: call of overloaded 'C(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)' is ambiguous
// вызов конструктора неоднозначен : или A или B
// C c0 { { 0 } } ;

C c1 { A { 1 } } ;

C c2 { B { 2 } } ;
```